# MS Access SQL replace NULL in field value

Tags: ms-access

I would like to show the value  "NONE" if the value in a field is null OR its value if
the field is not null from a table using select statement.
The statement may be similar to this:

```
select iif(isnull(spouse),"NONE",spouse) as spouse from biodata
```

Comment: Well, there's a name conflict, in that the alias is the same name as the underlying field. To work, it would have to be more specific: `IIf(IsNull(biodata.spouse),"NONE",biodata.spouse) As spouse`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
SELECT Nz(spouse,"NONE") AS Nzspouse FROM biodata
```

`Nz()` replaces `spouse` with `"NONE"` if `spouse` was `NULL`, otherwise it returns `spouse`.